# Correlation for multiple categorical variables tableau

Tags: r, correlation, categorical-data

## Question updated!!

I have 15 columns of categorical variables and I want the correlation among them. The data set is 20,000+ long and the data set looks like this:

```
state | job | hair_color | car_color | marital_status
NY    | cs  | brown      | blue      | s
FL    | mt  | black      | blue      | d
NY    | md  | blond      | white     | m
NY    | cs  | brown      | red       | s
```

Notice that 1st row and last row `NY`, `cs`, and `s` repeats. I want to find out that kind of patterns. NY and cs is highly correlated. I need to rank the combination of values in the columns. Hope now the question make sense. Please notice that is **NOT** counting `NY` or `cs`. Is about finding out how many times `NY` and `blond` appears together in the same row. I need to do that for all values by row. Hope now this make sense.

I tried to utilize `cor()` with R but since these are categorical variables the function doesn't work. How can I work with this data set to find the correlation among them?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to measure with `cor()`?  For example, is `cor(c("red","blue"), c("red","yellow"))` higher than, the same as, or lower than `cor(c("red","blue"), c("red","brown"))`?

Comment: No, is not ordinary. For id 1 I have 15 colors, for id 2 other 15 colors, and  I have 20,000 id's. Colors don't repeat by id. I want to find how each color correlates with the other colors. With `cor()`, R returns a table matrix with all the variables and how each variable correlates. Colors variable are not ordinary, they're just categorical. Make sense what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Yes, but for 16 variables instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to refer to [Ways to calculate similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2981743/6455166).  Suppose your data is

```
d <- structure(list(state = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("FL", 
"NY"), class = "factor"), job = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L
), .Label = c("bs", "cs", "md", "mt"), class = "factor"), hair_color = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("black", "blond", "brown"), class = "factor"), 
    car_color = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("blue", 
    "red", "white"), class = "factor"), marital_status = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("d", "m", "s"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("state", 
"job", "hair_color", "car_color", "marital_status"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Data:

```
> d
  state job hair_color car_color marital_status
1    NY  cs      brown      blue              s
2    FL  bs      brown       red              d
3    FL  mt      black      blue              d
4    NY  md      blond     white              m
5    NY  cs      brown       red              s
```

We can calculate the "dissimilarities" between observations:

```
library(cluster)
daisy(d, metric = "euclidean")
```

Output:

```
> daisy(d, metric = "euclidean")
Dissimilarities :
    1   2   3   4
2 0.8            
3 0.8 0.6        
4 0.8 1.0 1.0    
5 0.2 0.6 1.0 0.8

Metric :  mixed ;  Types = N, N, N, N, N 
Number of objects : 5
```

which tells us that observations 1 and 5 are least dissimilar.  With many observations, it is obviously impossible to visually inspect the dissimilarity matrix, but we can filter out the pairs that fall below a certain threshold, e.g.

```
out <- daisy(d, metric = "euclidean")
pairs <- expand.grid(2:5, 1:4)
pairs <- pairs[pairs[,1]!=pairs[,2],]
similars <- pairs[which(out<.8),]
```

Given a threshold of 0.8,

```
> similars
  Var1 Var2
4    5    1
6    3    2
8    5    2
```